# iOS private API for changing user settings

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi

I need to enable mobile data from user setting from my today extension.
This option is missing from iOS control center, so I want to be able to enable it from widget. This is solely for personal use, so any method is welcomed.

Comment: Thanks! this is far more better than what I've found.

Comment: Any luck with the private APIs?  I'm trying to change the system time for testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a complete list of private API for several iOS versions [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers).